# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) angular js + ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

[image]

This is the error im having from Google Devt Tools. Anyone knows the problem? I tried to change in many times including the file structure and the stateProvider (no controllers for that) in app.js file but it does not seem to be the issue. (script is included in app.js with correct file name and directory)

In addition, my logout and submitPost buttons arent working as well.

**newpost.html**

```
<div class="modal slide-in-up" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
 <!-- Modal header bar -->
   <header class="bar bar-header bar-secondary">
      <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
      <h1 class="title">New Shout</h1>
      <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="submitPost()">Done</button>
   </header>

<!-- Modal content area --> 
   <ion-content class="padding has-header">
       <form class ng-submit="submitPost()" ng-show="signedIn()"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="post.title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link" ng-model="post.url">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</div>
```

**controller.js file**

```
app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $firebase, $location, Post, Auth, $ionicModal) {
    $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};

    // Create and load the Modal
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('newpost.html', function(modal) {
      $scope.taskModal = modal;
    }, {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    });
    // Open our new task modal
    $scope.submitPost = function () {
      Post.create($scope.post).then(function (postId) {   
        $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};  
        $location.path('/posts/' + postId);              
        $scope.taskModal.show();  
      });
    };
    $scope.close = function() {
      $scope.taskModal.hide();
    };
    $scope.logout = function () {
        Auth.logout();
    };
});
```

**List of items page, post.html**

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
   <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="submitPost()">New</button>
   <h1 class="title"><b><a class="navbar-brand" href="#/posts">MyApp</a></b></h1>
   <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="logout()">Logout</button>
</ion-header-bar>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**404** literally means that file was not found. **It's simple as that**. Check if the URL is right, and there are no rediretions being done(use fiddler). Perhaps the protocol should be https:// istead of http://? Perhaps you need "**www**" in url?

Click the url given in Chrome and see if the file exists.

Comment: Thanks @Erti-Chris Eelmaa When I click on the error, it says Cannot GET /newpost.html. 

I kind of spotted an error that $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('newpost.html', function(modal) should be $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/newpost.html', function(modal)

But now when I run grunt serve, its perpetually loading ... and I cant press F12 to troubleshoot..

Comment: That's because you are in infinite recursion. Your newpost.html is creating always new NavCtrl, and NavCtrl is creating always newpost.html, it goes on forever.

Comment: @Erti-Chria Eelmaa any suggestion how to correct the code? I thought putting nav.ctrl in the html just means it uses that controller. How does the recursion occur?

Comment: Get rid of ng-controller="NavCtrl" and put it to "body" tag or closer where you don't reload the controller every time.

Answer (score 12):

Change `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">` from index.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone is interested, but Experienced a similar problem when trying to upload to firebase storage here is how i resolved it.
[The Error screenshot where upload fails with 503 and then 400 after 75% progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kueIA.png)

The code segment I use for Upload is

```
 //Event: data.Event,
       // Date: data.Date,
      // Time: data.Time
var data = getData();
data.filename=uploadfile.name;
var metadata = {
    customMetadata: {
       data
    }
}

var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child("features");

console.log("Filenames to upload :" + uploadfile.name);

var fileRef = storageRef.child(uploadfile.name);

var uploadTask = fileRef.put(uploadfile,metadata);
```

The Problem was with custom meta data, once I changed it to like this,

```
  var metadata = {
    customMetadata: {
        Event: data.Event,
        Date: data.Date,
        Time: data.Time
    }
}
```

the upload started working. So, if there is an error in setting custom meta data, firebase errors out and possible does not provide that as a reason.

Screenshot of working here
[successful upload once the custom meta data is corrected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puoaL.png)